# Cannot run python -m unittest locally. SPARK_HOME variable is not set properly

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyspark

I want to run all my test modules together before uploading them to Jenkins build, so I use `python -m unittest tests/*.py`  command from my devops-config.yml file.

But I receive FileNotFoundError:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (tests.test_sdk.TestUtils)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tests/test_sdk.py", line 26, in setUpClass
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_dir_path) \
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 367, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 62, in _launch_gateway
    SPARK_HOME = _find_spark_home()
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/find_spark_home.py", line 65, in _find_spark_home
    paths = [os.path.abspath(p) for p in paths]
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/find_spark_home.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    paths = [os.path.abspath(p) for p in paths]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 376, in abspath
    cwd = os.getcwd()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I run each .py file by itself from using PyCharm, it runs without any errors, but when I run them all together from terminal command line, all the files with spark tests fail with the same FileNotFoundError.

Spark session settings are the same for all test files:

```
import unittest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class TestUtils(unittest.TestCase):
    spark: SparkSession = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        derby_conf = f"-Dderby.system.home=/tmp/derby"
        warehouse_dir_path = f"/tmp/warehouse"
        cls.spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').enableHiveSupport() \
            .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", derby_conf) \
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_dir_path) \
            .config("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1") \
            .getOrCreate()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.spark.stop()

    def test_util_function(self):
        self.spark.sql(f"CREATE DATABASE {db}")
        ... some tests...
```

I also tried to run with:

`export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/lib/python3.6" && python -m unittest tests/*.py`

and with:

`export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3" && python -m unittest tests/*.py`

But with no success

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: `export SPARK_HOME=/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark`.

Comment: Thanks @Czaporka!
I tried it and it gave me a new error: ```Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number```

Answer (score 0):

You need both of these

```sh
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/' # update your correct Java home path here
export SPARK_HOME='/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark'
```